# Is there a canonical way to go back from $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ (presheaves) to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: category-theory, representable-functor

Is there a “canonical” way to go back from $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ (category of presheaves) to $\mathbb{C}$. Here we define $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ to be the category of functors from $\mathbb{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mathrm{SET}$. I just started category theory, and it seems that the Yoneda embedding is sort of the canonical way to go from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$. So I was wondering if going back is just as “easy”.

Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can recover a category $\mathcal{C}$ from its category of presheaves, up to Cauchy completion. In particular that means that if $\mathcal{C}$ is Cauchy complete, then you can recover it (up to equivalence) from its category of presheaves. A lot of information about this can be found on the [nLab page about Cauchy complete categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+complete+category).

Let me just state the major relevant points here. The numbering in this answer refers to the (current) numbering on the nLab page.

> **Definition.** A category $\mathcal{C}$ is called *Cauchy complete* if every idempotent splits. That is, for every $e: C \to C$ such that $ee = e$, there are $r: C \to D$ and $i: D \to C$ such that $ri = Id_D$ and $ir = e$.

Note that if a category has equalizers, then it is Cauchy complete (take $i$ to be the equalizer of $e$ and $Id_C$, and $r$ the universal arrow corresponding to $e$).

Then Proposition 2.3 states that if $\mathcal{C}$ is Cauchy complete, then it can be recovered from $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^\text{op}}$ as the full subcategory of "tiny objects" or "small projective objects".

> **Definition.** In a cocomplete category $\mathcal{E}$ we say that an object $E$ is *tiny* or *small projective* if the hom-functor $\operatorname{Hom}(E, -): \mathcal{E} \to \mathbf{Set}$ preserves all small colimits.

There are equivalent characterisations possible. For example, we could also recover $\mathcal{C}$ as the indecomposable projectives.

If $\mathcal{C}$ is not Cauchy complete, then taking the tiny objects will give us the Cauchy completion $\bar{\mathcal{C}}$. We cannot hope to do better, because there is an equivalence of categories
$$
\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^\text{op}} \simeq \mathbf{Set}^{\bar{\mathcal{C}}^\text{op}}.
$$

Comment: Interesting! How do you gain intuition about the meaning of $\mathrm{Hom}(E,-)$ preserving small colimits?

Comment: @goblin Maybe the [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tiny+object) on those things helps a bit? I haven't thought too much about what exactly this condition means. If you understand projective objects, then they are equivalently the indecomposable projectives. The property indecomposable ([nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tiny+object)) is easier to understand I think.

Answer (score 3):

For another sense of "go back", you might ask for a *functor* $\hat C\to C$ somehow nicely related to the Yoneda embedding. While this seems a bit unlikely since $\hat C$ is much "bigger" than $C$, it is actually extremely common for locally small $C$ that the Yoneda embedding has a left adjoint $L:\hat C\to C$. Such categories are called [total.](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/total+category)